# How to reduce the space between nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to make the nodes in the following `vector`-illustration touch each other. But no matter what I do to `text width` or `node distance` the distance between the nodes stays the same.

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzstyle{cell} = [rectangle, draw, text width=1.3cm ]
\tikzstyle{capx} = [rectangle, draw, text width=1.3cm, color=black!40  ]

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={text centered,  minimum height=1.5em, minimum width=1.5cm,node distance=0pt},
    background rectangle/.style={fill=black!10},show background rectangle,
    ]

   \node at (10,0) [capx] (n5) {leer};
   \node at (12,0) [capx] (n6) {leer};
   \node at (14,0) [capx] (n7) {leer};

   \node at (0,0) [cell] (n0) {wert};    
   \node at (2,0) [cell] (n1) {wert};
   \node at (4,0) [cell] (n2) {wert};
   \node at (6,0) [cell] (n3) {wert};
   \node at (8,0) [cell] (n4) {wert};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
  (-0.6,0.5) -- (8.8,0.5) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=18pt] 
  {\hskip6ex size()};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt,color=black!40]
  (-0.6,-0.5) -- (14.8,-0.5) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-18pt,color=black!40] 
  {\hskip6ex capacity()};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: bad vector]

Comment: Also look at the follow-up question [How does 'right=of' and 'right of=' do, and what does 'node distance=' do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157144/4039)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `positioning` library and place your nodes using `right= of <name>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
  cell/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=1.3cm,outer sep=0pt},
  capx/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=1.3cm, color=black!40,outer sep=0pt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={align=center, minimum height=1.5em, minimum width=1.5cm,node distance=0pt},
    background rectangle/.style={fill=black!10},show background rectangle,
    ]


   \node at (0,0) [cell] (n0) {wert};    
   \node[right=of n0,cell] (n1) {wert};
   \node[right=of n1,cell] (n2) {wert};
   \node[right=of n2,cell] (n3) {wert};
   \node[right=of n3,cell] (n4) {wert};

   \node[right=of n4,capx] (n5) {leer};
   \node[right=of n5,capx] (n6) {leer};
   \node[right=of n6,capx] (n7) {leer};

\draw[
   decorate,
  decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}
]
  ([yshift=4pt]n0.north west) -- 
  node [black,yshift=18pt] {size()}
  ([yshift=4pt]n4.north east) ;

\draw[
  decorate,
  decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror},
  color=black!40
]
  ([yshift=-4pt]n0.south west) -- 
    node [black,yshift=-18pt,color=black!40]  {capacity()}
  ([yshift=-4pt]n7.south east) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Some remarks:

1. `\tikzstyle` is deprecated; I changed to `\tikzset` instead.
2. Use the anchors of the existing nodes to place the braces.
3. Set `outer sep` to `0pt` so the lines of the nodes nicely overlap.
4. Notice that I also changed the placement of the nodes for the braces.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I will try to work them in. i have some difficulties, though. a) `every node/.style={...,node distance=0pt},` seems to place all nodes onto each other; changing it to `node distance=1.5cm` spreads the nodes, but my old problem is back. b) are you sure about `[right=of n0,cell]`? not rather `[right of= n0,cell]`? The first fails, the latter parses. Or do I have a wrong version?

Comment: @towi Yes, I am sure about `right=of n0`; the syntax `right of=n0` is deprecated; make sure that you are loading the `positioning` library and that you are using a recent version (at least 2.10) of PGF/TikZ (you can find which version are you using processing this simple document `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pgfversion
\end{document}`)

Comment: 2.10 it is. Uh, that is interesting: When I change `right of=` to `right=of` all nodes get spaced with a huge gap -- because I also changed `node distance=0cm` for my `right of=`-variant to work properly. But with your `right=of`-notation I need `node distance=0cm` and it looks fine! Can you explain the workings of those two variants to me? What does `right=of` to differently then (deprecated) `right of=`, and what is `node distance=...` doing? Or wait, I make another question of it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way without using `positioning` library. We place the `node`s at `previous node.east` and set the anchor to `west` so that they touch each other.

```
\node[anchor=west,cell] at (n1.east) (n2) {wert};
```

The `outer sep` should be zero as in Gonzalo's answer. You can keep the key `node distance=1.5cm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
  cell/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=1.3cm,outer sep=0pt},
  capx/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=1.3cm, color=black!40,outer sep=0pt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={align=center, minimum height=1.5em, minimum width=1.5cm,node distance=1.5cm},
    background rectangle/.style={fill=black!10},show background rectangle,
    ]


   \node at (0,0) [cell] (n0) {wert};
   \node[cell,anchor=west] at (n0.east) (n1) {wert};
   \node[anchor=west,cell] at (n1.east) (n2) {wert};
   \node[anchor=west,cell] at (n2.east) (n3) {wert};
   \node[anchor=west,cell] at (n3.east) (n4) {wert};

   \node[anchor=west,capx] at (n4.east) (n5) {leer};
   \node[anchor=west,capx] at (n5.east) (n6) {leer};
   \node[anchor=west,capx] at (n6.east) (n7) {leer};

\draw[
   decorate,
  decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}
]
  ([yshift=4pt]n0.north west) --
  node [black,yshift=18pt] {size()}
  ([yshift=4pt]n4.north east) ;

\draw[
  decorate,
  decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror},
  color=black!40
]
  ([yshift=-4pt]n0.south west) --
    node [black,yshift=-18pt,color=black!40]  {capacity()}
  ([yshift=-4pt]n7.south east) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, understood. I do require the `distance=1.5cm` then? I think I did not grasp the concept of the different node-dimensions, yet. Together with the many automatisms.